# How to make image on unbutton persist until its not changed by the user .?

Tags: ios, checkbox, uibutton

I am working on `UIButton` as a check box, when I press button than checkbox selected image is appear and when press again checkbox unselected image is appear. if I press button image is appear, but it again disappear when I come back to that view again.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     _car.delegate = self;
     _car.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;


     [_PreCheck setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbx_unchecked@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [_PreCheck setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbx@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
     [_PreCheck addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
    if ((checkBoxSelected = !checkBoxSelected)) {
        [_PreCheck setSelected:checkBoxSelected];
        NSLog(@"selected");
        NSString *selected = @"selected";
        NSUserDefaults *select = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [select setObject:selected forKey:@"checkboxselected"];
        [select synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not selected");
        [_PreCheck setSelected:notselected];
    }
}
```

Comment: are you leaving the view i.e. destroying it from navigation hierarchy, like going back or dismiss?

Comment: when i leave view and again come back to that view again image is disappear

Comment: if you are leaving the view then how can that show the selected Image. for that kind of task you need to store button selected state and when you come back you can check by its stored state and set image for button again.

Comment: image should not be disappear even the app is close once i checkbox selected

Comment: You have to put if else condition to check "selected" or not from NSUserDefault which is you are storing in event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your posted code your `ViewDidLoad` must be check with current NSUserDefaults store value is selected or not based on it first you need to set button check uncheck image. so following is your `viewDidLoad` Code look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _car.delegate = self;
    _car.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

     NSString *state = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"btnstate"];

    if([state isEqualToString:@"selected"])
    {
     [_PreCheck setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbx@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_PreCheck setSelected:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [_PreCheck setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"checkbx_unchecked@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_PreCheck setSelected:NO];

    }

    [_PreCheck addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Now set the method for check-uncheck like following:

```
-(void)checkboxSelected:(UIButton*)sender
{
     sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    if([sender isSelected])
    {
        [_PreCheck setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbx@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"selected" forKey:@"btnstate"];

    }
    else
    {
        [_PreCheck setBackgroundImage:[UIImage im ageNamed:@"checkbx_unchecked@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"notselected" forKey:@"btnstate"];
    }

}
```

Hope that work or you. just replace your code with my posted code no need to do other changes.

Comment: you are welcome. you can also done with button state selected and normal image at viewdidLoad then you dont need to put change image code in IBAction

Comment: ok sir thats fine for me because i need to do more task on selected and unselected

Answer (score 1):

Store the button state in `NSUSerDefaults`.

Then In `viewDidLoad` get the state and based on that load image.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Your code

    // get selected state from user defaults.
     BOOL selected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"buttonstateKey"];
     if (selected)
     {
      // set selected image
     }
     else 
     {
     // set regular image
     }
}
```